# Round the corners of a button or EditText

Tags: android-edittext

In my android application I want to round the corners of my buttons and of my EditText. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using 9-patch that should work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a new `background.xml` file with the following XML:

```
<shape android:xmlns="schemas.android.com/res/apk android:shape="rectangle">
    <corner android:radious="3dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="#000"/>
</shape>
```

You can write the attribute in the EditText properties to create the round border, like so:

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```